# Wait for an event to finish (threading)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I need to wait for an event to finish before continuing.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Stream> pair in this.XMLCollection)
{
    ...
    this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<LogToApplicationEvent>().Publish(credentials);
    //wait 
    ...
}
```

Before continuing I need to wait for "login" event to execute complately.
I tried using `Task.Factory`, but it did not work for me, or I cant use it right...

This code is on presenter, but the event updates the main UI.

```
//publish
public virtual void Publish(TPayload payload)
{
   base.InternalPublish(payload);
}
```

Comment: What's the signature of `Publish`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least two possible solutions:

BackgroundWorker

Use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to execute your code, and use the [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event to execute the code that is run after completion.

A BackgroundWorker wraps the event based asynchronous pattern into a very easy to use mechanism, complete with progress reporting and cancellation. See this [`BackgroundWorker tutorial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and this SO answer .

**Tasks (.NET 4.0 and above)**

Use a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) object, and use the [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) method to define the code that needs to be executed after completion of the first task.

Answer (score 2):

`Event Aggregator` publishing and subscribing event pattern is `synchronous`. You need not to worry about it.

So, it won't resume until its subscribers are finished executing its delegates.

**Assumption** - You are using inbuilt [Event Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) class provided by Microsoft.

Comment: but it does ... the code behind the event tries to do something but fails because the login has not performed. Actually if I observe the UI login event fires with few second delay (it opens a popup)