# Progress bar (spinner) not animated when background thread is working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I have a background worker that does some work. I want to have a spinner on main control indicating that app is working. But looks like threading is preventing my spinner from animating (sometimes it doesnt even show)... can some one explain why it is not working (probably because sleeping the thread) and perhaps guide me to a solution with minimal code changes :)

Best regards, no9.

```
public void StartProcess(object obj)
{

  this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ActionEvent>().Publish(new Message(EMessageType.Info)
  {
    Title = "Start",
    Description = "Starting action..."
  });

  Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
  Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);

  try
  {
    this.Document = null;
    Dictionary<string, Stream> tmp = this.GetContent();
    //start and show the spinner
    this.View.ShowDocumentProgressSpinner(true);
    Worker.RunWorkerAsync(tmp);
  }

  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "LogAndSwallow");
    this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<ActionEvent>().Publish(new Message(EMessageType.Error)
     {
       Title = "Error",
       Description = "There was an error processing your action."
     });
  }
  finally
  {
    this.View.ShowActionButton(false);
  }
}


private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  var logger = new ActionLoggerAndViewUpdater(this.eventAggregator, this.View);
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Stream> pair in (Dictionary<string, Stream>)e.Argument)
  {
    using (Stream stream = pair.Value)
    {
        //setting the document fires login event that changes stuff on presenter (current class instance)
        this.Document = new Document(stream);

        //check if ok to continue
        while (!this.IsLoggedInForTheWorkingDocument)
        //wait of the login stuff to complete
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

      System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
      {
        //this depends on the login and takes some time to process
        this.DoSomeStuff();
      }));
    }
  }
}

private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  //stop and hide the spinner
  this.View.ShowDocumentProgressSpinner(false);
  ...
}
```

Comment: if  this.View.ShowDocumentProgressSpinner(true); is updating your UI then you should use this in worker_DoWork method, because this is in different thread.

Comment: its a control ... and it does not allow to be updated from another thread than the main UI thread...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you invoke something on your background worker? The background workers whole purpose is to *not* run in the UI thread and block it. Do not invoke a long running process from the worker, it defeats it's purpose.

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  var logger = new ActionLoggerAndViewUpdater(this.eventAggregator, this.View);
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Stream> pair in (Dictionary<string, Stream>)e.Argument)
  {
    using (Stream stream = pair.Value)
    {
        this.Document = new Document(stream);

        // this should REALLY be handled by an event, not busy waiting:
        while (!this.IsLoggedInForTheWorkingDocument) 
        //wait of the login stuff to complete
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // removed the invoking, this is supposed to run in the background, right?
        this.DoSomeStuff();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the stuff updates the UI, do I need to use UI thread... its a design I cannot circle around ... calling the "DoSomeStuff" without invoking throws me "another thread" exception.

Comment: If it *has to* update the UI, then you should skip your background worker. It's no longer background work. Maybe you can find a better strategy, for example producing results first, in the background and then updateing the UI when you have done the heavy lifting in the background.

Comment: I had to use it. I will try to expain. When setting "this.Document" events are fired in the background that perform login, update UI and change some stuff on class I am holding all this. Only when login is complete and only then i can call "DoSomeStuff". I was able to achieve this only with bckgWorker. See my original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515598/wait-for-an-event-to-finish-threading. This events are fired when setting "this.Document"

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with this approach, it's a common issue, for example, in uploading a large document where the UI has a progress indicator. Saying 'don't use a background thread' is not really that useful.

Comment: @Dave Then you use the ReportProgressFeature. Anyway, Invoking the whole function is total overkill and will block the UI. Therefore here a backgroundworker would be useless. What can be done is putting the invoke *inside* the function and *only* invoke the parts that actually handle UI. But to be honest, with all that publish/subscribe patterns in the posts, it seems like a total hack to use Invokes. If there already *is* a pub/sub infrastructure, it should be used.

Comment: i feel that in about 10 minutes i wont give a rats-ass about the damn spinner :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your worker runs in another thread, it cannot update the UI thread as it progresses, hence the behaviour. See this other, similar question [Updating GUI (WPF) using a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253088/c-updating-gui-wpf-using-a-different-thread).

Essentially you need to call control.Dispatcher.Invoke to get your UI to update from the other thread

Comment: I have tried putting the progress spinner inside the worker and updating it via main app dispatcher ... same result

Comment: The spinner can sit in the UI layer, where it should be. The problem is dealt with in detail here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx, linked through an answer on the previous SO question